# C code to detect whether the Ethernet cable is connected or not

Tags: operating-system, embedded, embedded-linux, embedded-resource, ethernet

function to check Interface link(UP/DOWN)

Details: if two system's are connected using Ethernet on known interface with static IP, if we remove Ethernet this program should detect the link status,

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: "*if two system's are connected using Ethernet ...*" -- Somewhat unusual to connect two hosts to each other (aka an ad hoc connection).  Use of a switch is more likely in a LAN. Regardless detection of just the Ethernet cable (in the local socket) is not as informative as you assume. The salient condition usually is a working, live session with the other host.

Comment: Link status is reported via sysfs. You may poll that file for updates.